# gitlab-runner only run pipeline when `gitlab-runner run` is on

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I registered a runner on local gitlab environment. The runner will only execute the pipeline when there is a process is running the command of `gitlab-runner run`.

Once the process stops running the command, jobs will remain pending.

It is a linux(ubuntu) runner with shell executor, I tried to run `systemctl start gitlab-runner && systemctl enable gitlab-runner && systemctl restart gitlab-runner` but seems not work.

One of the thing is that `gitlab-runner run` will pick up jobs only being runed not as root.

Comment: Facing the same issue, have you found any solution to this?

Comment: @angadsingh still trying, haven't found any solution. maybe add `gitlab-runner run` as start up

Comment: @angadsingh basically the gitlab-runner need to be registered with sudo, otherwise it must be manually started

Comment: Check the ExecStart command in /etc/systemd/system/gitlab-runner.service, run it manually and see what's going on.